# How to actually change the maximum number of columns in SQLITE

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, max

So I have a sqlite3 db, which I access from Python (2.7), where I would like to store more than the by default allowed 2.000 columns. I understand that there is a setting or command, SQLITE_MAX_COLUMN, which I can alter, so that my database can store up to ~32.000 columns. My question is how do I in practice set the maximum number of columns to for example 30.000 - what is the specific code, that I should run? Hope my question is clearly stated. Thanks

Comment: ... do you really need more than 2000 **columns**? Then your table is very badly designed. Aren't you probably confusing between **rows** and **columns**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a compile-time parameter for SQLite itself.  As in, you'll need to recompile the SQLite library in order to change it.  Nothing you can do in Python will be able to overcome this.

Comment: So how do I go about changing this parameter?

Comment: Recompile with `-DSQLITE_MAX_COLUMN=32000`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Recompiling seems to be a somewhat complicated process, so I think it'll be easier for me just to transpose the data I am trying to store, that way there will only be ~200 columns.

Comment: I really wish there were a binary that had been made with this flag.